# How to run compiled C++ program on startup?

Tags: command-line, startup

I have compiled and made an exucutable C++ program in ubuntu.But It only runs in terminal.that is I have to give the ./example command in terminal.If I click it nothing happens and says no suitable apps. Now what should I do to run this program on startup.?Even if it is in the terminal not in X-term that would do. But I have to start this program on every startup. I tried this command, but nothing happens on startup,

```
gnome-terminal -e "./routine" --working-directory "/home/tamim"
```

.

Answer (score 1):

You can call it from `~/.bashrc` file. Put path to your executable at the end of it:

```
~/Documents/myCompiledExecutable
```